# Quadratic Bosonic Hamiltonian Expectation Value for Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, second-quantization

I'm given a quadratic bosonic Hamiltonian $$\hat{H}=\sum^N_{k=1}\omega_k\hat{b}^\dagger_k\hat{b}_k$$ with plane wave solutions $$\hat{b}_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum^N_{n=1}\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi kn}{N}\right)\hat{b}_n$$

The question involves evaluating the expectation value on the ground state of the Hamiltonian for the operators $\hat{b}_i\hat{b}^\dagger_i\hat{b}_j\hat{b}_j^\dagger$ and $\hat{b}_i\hat{b}_j^\dagger\hat{b}_j\hat{b}_i^\dagger$ for lattice positions $i$ and $j$.

I'm quite unsure about how to go about solving this problem, so any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Roger's answer, but would add a few hints/comments:

0. As Roger said in the comments to his answer, you need to find the ground state of your Hamiltonian before you can calculate any expectation values. This will depend on your specific dispersion $\omega_k$ (Hint: where is the minimum of this dispersion?)
1. You've stated this Hamiltonian describes bosons, not fermions. This invalidates Roger's comment about things being filled up to the Fermi energy. Remember that more than one boson can occupy a given single-particle state.
2. Once you have the ground state, to calculate expectation values, think back to the standard harmonic oscillator problem from your first QM class. How would you calculate $\left<\psi\middle|a^\dagger a\middle|\psi\right>$ in a state $\left|\psi\right>$ that is in the ground state of the harmonic oscillator? What about the first excited state? What about the n'th excited state, where $\left|\psi\right> = \left|n\right>$? What about calculating  $\left<\psi\middle|a^\dagger a a^\dagger a\middle|\psi\right>$? If you can do these calculations, you can solve your problem, which uses exactly the same kind of manipulations. Just remember your commutation relations.

Answer (score 0):

Straighforward approach would be to invert the Fourier transform:
$$\hat{b}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum^N_{k=1}\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi kn}{N}\right)\hat{b}_k$$
(Please check the coefficients and the summation limits before applying.)

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm a bit more lost than what my OP might've implied, but what would I then do once I have this?

Comment: You take four such operators to form a product $\hat{b}_i\hat{b}^\dagger_i\hat{b}_j\hat{b}_j^\dagger$ and average it in respect to your state: $\langle \psi|\hat{b}_i\hat{b}^\dagger_i\hat{b}_j\hat{b}_j^\dagger|\psi\rangle$, which is probably filled up to certain Fermi energy (which is expressed in terms of $k$).

Comment: Right, but I would still need to first find the ground state itself to do this, right?

Comment: @roo_sado That depends on the problem that you are solving. Your post contains too little information about it for a serious discussion. I suppose it is something like a chain of atoms with periodic boundary conditions and specified Fermi level. So you diagonalizing it by the transform given in the OP and then fill the states up to the Fermi level. There is a lot of material here that should have been covered in your lecture notes or the textbook...